# Remmina to Ubuntu slow, but to windows OK

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

I have been using Remmina on my main PC to access win7 and win8.1 PCs (both using TightVNC Server) and it is suitably fast enough to be productive.

In my pursuit to make all PCs in our home Ubuntu, I installed 14.04 in dual boot on the win7 PC. All good, but using Remmina it is excruciatingly slow, taking almost two seconds for the cursor to move down one line in Gedit. Totally unusable.

Is there something I can do that will give me the speed Remmina has with windows?

I have done some searching, but after a full day at it, found nothing to help speed this up.

{edit}
Setup uses the defaults at both ends. I set remote ufw to allow 5900, other than that it is whatever Ubuntu/Remmina comes with. Plus, I set the screen resolution to the fastest, "Poor" which is visually OK.

Comment: why don't you try other alternatives to Remmina ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/936204/edit) your question and add more details on how to have setup the remote Ubuntu PC. Some remote setups don't work well with Unity desktop.

Comment: @OWADVL, thanks, your suggestions would be? I have not been able to find anything other than RealVNC and I do not like their deceptive approach. If I use "sudo apt-get install tightvncserver" it installs RealVNC server. That ain't honest to my way of thinking. At least not without first asking me if I want RealVNC.

Comment: Well, why not just use TightVNC to connect or its other version UltraVNC that works similarly? They both have Tight/Ultra VNC Viewer that allows you to connect remotely to another device.

Comment: Haa Ha, they wanted me to enable Javascript and then, when I did, they asked me to disable ad-blocking or just look at a blank page. Great marketing guys. Now where did I put my wallet!

Comment: Connect via Putty to destination pc open `x11vnc` session in putty  and connect with free version of ultra vnc viewer, it's works 100% without payment because I use it my job.